# Jenkins - triggering a parameterized build

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I have project configured in Jenkins that polls an SCM and begins a build when a change is posted. There is a post build action to build another project. The question I have is, the project that is being built afterwards has its own parameters. How do I know which parameter is specified when the post-build action triggers? Right now if if I use 'Choices', is it just picking the first one? How do I have it pick other ones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, let's take it one by one :)

1. If you want to see which parameter were used, You can install this plugin: [Show Build Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Show+Build+Parameters+Plugin)
2. If you want to trigger a build with a specific parameters, use this plugin: [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)