# Jenkins: Testing on every commit AND releasing on click with the same project

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

1) I want to run my testsuite on every commit, so Jenkins should poll SVN, make an update and run the tests. That's possible without problems, BUT...

2) I also want to be able to create builds, which additionally covers creating zip archives and transferring them via scp to a remote server.

How is this possible within the same project?

Comment: Does it have to be the same project?

Comment: Yep, it has. But I think the solution might be a variant of parametrized builds -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456074/jenkins-triggering-a-parameterized-build

However, as the documentation states "When build triggers are used to start a build, there's no way to pass parameters. This includes SCM polling, downstream builds, and periodic builds. Instead, the specified default values will be used for string, boolean and choice parameters."

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Jenkins SCP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin)? You can add an aditional build step in the existing project itself which creates your builds, generates zip archives etc. And at last as a post build action publish the artifacts to a SCP repository. Will that help?