# Jenkins scheduled build Triggers with environment variable?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I want to build periodically with environment variable in jenkins:

```
#pseudo setting
H 17 * * * BUILD_FOR=gist-mail TOKEN_GIST_MAIL=some_token
H 17 * * * BUILD_FOR=pollyanna TOKEN_POLLYANNA=anothor_token
H 17 * * * BUILD_FOR=fenix-knight TOKEN_FENIX_KNIGHT=alternative_token
```

These variables do not change dynamically, given in advance.

I got a error below:

```
Invalid input: "10 17 * * * BUILD_FOR=fenix-knight": line 1:12: expecting EOF, found ' '
```

How do I pass different environment variable to each build trigger? My work around is create each jobs.

My executing shell below:

```
gem install bundler
ruby -i -pe '$_.gsub! /^ruby/, "#ruby"' Gemfile
bundle
BUILD_FOR=fenix-knight bundle exec rake tachikoma:load tachikoma:fetch tachikoma:bundle tachikoma:pull_request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parameterized build plugin for your situation [Jenkins - triggering a parameterized build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456074/jenkins-triggering-a-parameterized-build) has a good demonstration of how to use it and also another plugin to show the parameters which went into it.

You could also look at the multijob plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin to run one underlying job with separate parameters

Comment: I create 2 jenkins jobs, using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). The first job is build piriodically as crontab, and using `Trigger parameterized build on other projects`. The second one is actual job.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your schedules are the same but you want to kick off 3 builds with different environment variables. I think on way is to first create a job with parameters. Parameters should be holding your environment variables. Then create another job with actual schedule to call your job created, in build step you use the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) to actually kick off the job with parameters.